# Unity iOS OpenGL app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, unity-game-engine

I have an iOS Unity Game developed. In order to help tester to track the bug, I have added one more module which will take the snapshot and then show a view to the tester to Annotate it. I am using Apple's GLPaint example : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html .

When I start annotating, I pause the Unity game and resume when the annotation is over. But there is one problem, when I try to resume the unity game, the app crashes weirdly with some error GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Check the trace log
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used Unity, but it smells like the current GL context changes when you bring up the annotation view, and isn't restored properly when you return to the game. Give saving/restoring Unity's GL context a shot (see: EAGLContext +currentContext & +setCurrentContext:).